# Why is inductive coupling negligible at low frequencies?

Tags: rf, transmission-line, inductance, interference, crosstalk

I've been reading some papers from the early telephone era. I see a lot of statements thrown around like "crosstalk at low or voice frequencies, where inductive coupling is negligible..." with no explanation as to *why* inductive coupling is negligible at those frequencies.

What makes the inductive coupling negligible at low frequencies? I'm interested in **why** these phenomena occur. Is there a case or transmission line geometry that would make inductive coupling **not** negligible at low frequencies?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Specifically embed in your question the quotation you read in some papers. I disagree with either your interpretation or, with the content but, I need to see the paper before I can be sure. If on the internet please link.

Comment: @Andyaka Here is the link: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6772848 Unfortunately, it is not freely available.

Comment: I can't be expected to pay for it can I. Maybe screenshot the relevant portion and add it to your question.

Comment: @Andyaka I found a free version: https://ia601609.us.archive.org/4/items/bstj54-7-1227/bstj54-7-1227_text.pdf - Page 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've been reading some papers from the early telephone era. I see a lot of statements thrown around like "crosstalk at low or voice frequencies, where inductive coupling is negligible..."

The voltage induced in a victim "pair" due to the magnetic field around an agressor is based entirely on Faraday's law of induction.$$v_{induced}=\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$ where \$\phi\$ is the magnetic flux.

If the flux is due to a sinusoidal current in the aggressor then $$\phi=\Phi\text{sin}\omega t$$So applying the law$$v_{induced}=\Phi\omega\text{cos}\omega t$$

The fact that the induced voltage is a result of a rate-of-change means that at lower fequencies the coupling is reduced.

The twisted pair cables used back then had an approximately 1 twist per meter. Enough to maintain them adjecent in the cable, so the coupling over two twists essentially cancels. The wavelength at audio is so long that long twisting intervals can be used.

In modern cables operating into GHz, the factor \$\Phi\omega\$ is large requiring a tighter twist as high as 10 twists per inch and quadrature alignment of the pairs to reduce magnetic coupling. Some cables have physical separators to maintain a distance between pairs.

Comment: For the bit about twisted pairs, it would maybe help to clarify that you're not talking about coupling between the two paired wires, but rather reducing differential-mode coupling to nearby wires.

Comment: @GlennWillen:Crosstalk in telephone cables refers to coupling from one pair to another pair within the same cable. The question refers to inductive coupling specifically. I have adjusted the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Induced voltage is proportional to the time derivative of magnetic flux and thus grows with frequency.  Of course, the converse is true about induced magnetisation as the time derivative of dielectric field changes, but we don't do low frequency electronics in a vacuum.  We do it using electric conductors tightly packed with electrons, and their fundamental reaction is to electric fields.  To make them usefully interact with magnetic fields to any significant degree, we need to coil them into solenoids so that their movement is constrained to the direction of the circular electric fields caused by magnetic induction.

Now if we are talking about telephone lines, those are usually done in *pairs*.  A paired transmission line is notorious for having a *net* current of zero normally.  But that means that the magnetic field around such a paired line is zero as well.  Now phone lines are not coaxial, so the geometry is not perfectly cancelling and there is some magnetic field around them.  But they are twisted which makes them net neutral against large-scale external fields (like the magnetic field of the Earth) and they are twisted independently (with multiple pairs in a large cable pack, consciously done at different rates) so the net interaction between twisted cable pairs also tends to be close to zero.

A twisted line pair acts as a common-mode choke and will lose energy inductively for currents that aren't adding up to zero.  But what it does have is capacity between its conductors, and that primarily works against the differentially transmitted signal.

Answer (score 1):

> *What makes the inductive coupling negligible at low frequencies?*

It doesn't have to be.

Think about a mains AC transformer. It operates at 50 or 60 Hz and, does it suffer from problems of coupling primary to secondary via the core? No it doesn't. Does it rely on "inductive coupling"? Yes it does.

Maybe what you have read (or seen) is something like this: -

- the "primary" current is fixed and,
- the "secondary" is loosely inductively coupled to the primary then,
- coupling rises linearly with frequency because \$\frac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ rises linearly with frequency hence,
- induced voltage increases with frequency

And, the above is very true but, this depends on the "primary" current remaining fixed with frequency and, there's every chance that it may reduce linearly with frequency.

This is the reason transformers can be made to operate across a range of frequencies without attenuation; the primary magnetization current falls with frequency but, \$\frac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ increases with frequency.

Net effect is a flat frequency response.

---

The OP has revealed that his [source](https://archive.org/details/bstj54-7-1227/mode/2up) to be this: -

[image]

And, in that document, the **phrase inductive** coupling is used twice. Firstly as an assumption: -

[image]

And then here (based on the original assumption): -

[image]

Given that the original assumption is **generally** wrong, this document cannot be relied upon to either support or deny what the OP claims about inductive coupling.

Comment: You say the original assumption is "generally wrong", but fall short of a complete proof.  Since this is telephone, we can assume 600 ohm terminated lines, therefore the aggressor's current will be flat with frequency, and the postulate is reasonable. Bell Labs wouldn't make such a trivial mistake, they knew their systems very well indeed. Anyway, OP didn't ask for a proof or contradiction, merely clarification, and this fact (terminated lines) seems to be the missing key. Rather than contradicting, merely suggesting where these assumptions might not apply seems a reasonable approach.

Comment: Are you saying that you dispute the presence of inductive coupling as a phenomena because that’s what it reads like. Maybe I should have said inapplicable rather than wrong @TimWilliams

Comment: "as a phenomena" <-- considering my livelihood depends upon the function of inductive components, I would appreciate you not drawing a *reductio ad absurdum* from my comments. The difference is simply the proportion with frequency, which you propose *might* [under what conditions?] be flat; I (and BSTJ) provide a case where it is not flat.

Comment: I'm only critiquing the overall form or tone of your answer, not the facts within it. For example, where you say "and, there's every chance that it may reduce linearly with frequency", this is given generally, but it's not applicable to the example in question. It would be better to explain this as, "sometimes it is, sometimes it's not, and when it is, it's like this, and when it's not, it's like that". Does that help?